# How to find the previous and current row difference

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

This table has 2 rows for each id, not more than 2 rows for the id

```
id  date       amt
-------------------    
001 01/01/2012 100
001 01/12/2011 200
002 01/01/2013 100
002 01/12/2012 200
003 12/08/2012 500
003 31/12/2011 200
...
```

I want to display the `max(date)` of row for each id with current and previous row amt differnce

Expected Output

```
id  date       amt
------------------    
001 01/01/2012 100
002 01/01/2013 100
003 12/08/2012 300
...
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id VARCHAR(10), date DATE, amt INT)
INSERT @tbl VALUES
('001', CONVERT(DATE, '01/01/2012', 103), 100),
('001', CONVERT(DATE, '01/12/2011', 103), 200),
('002', CONVERT(DATE, '01/01/2013', 103), 100),
('002', CONVERT(DATE, '01/12/2012', 103), 200),
('003', CONVERT(DATE, '12/08/2012', 103), 500),
('003', CONVERT(DATE, '31/12/2011', 103), 200),
-- Added to display the one id - one row situation
('004', CONVERT(DATE, '14/02/2011', 103), 999),
('000', CONVERT(DATE, '02/02/2012', 103), 100),
('100', CONVERT(DATE, '09/09/2011', 103), 999)

;WITH a AS
(
    SELECT  id
            , amt
            , date      
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date ASC) num
            , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id) cnt
    FROM    @tbl
)

SELECT  t1.id
        , t1.date
        , ABS(t1.amt - t2.amt)
FROM    a t1
JOIN    a t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id AND t1.num = t2.num + 1)
OR      (t1.id = t2.id AND t2.cnt = 1)
```

Difference of first and second row for ids 1 and 2 is -100 so I added the `ABS` function that returns absolute value.

I also added sample data to show how the situation is handled when there is only one record per id.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
   SELECT *,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Date DESC) AS Rownum
   FROM Table1
), CTE2
AS
(
  SELECT 
    id, 
    date, 
    amt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS rank
  FROM CTE c1
  WHERE rownum = 1
)
SELECT 
  id, 
  date, 
  amt - ISNULL((SELECT c2.amt
                FROM CTE2 c2
                WHERE c1.rank - c2.rank = 1), 0)
FROM CTE2 c1;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e29f7/10)

Comment: @Gopal - OK, sorry. See my edit. But in the result set for the id = 2 the amount should be 100 not 200 because it has the max date so the difference between the current amt and the previous amt for that record will be 0 not 100 as you showed in the result set, and for the next record will be 400 not 300. Is this right?